# Android. Store/Save Edittext text as .html file to internal Storage

Tags: javascript, android

Beginner Here. Is it possible to Save a file on Internal Storage using different kinds of extensions? Specifically .html. What im trying to accomplish is to make a text editor using EditText and Save it on the Internal Storage and then Load it later. Compiler if you could say,specifically for Javascript. Any Help is appreciated.

NOTE: I have tried other Codes that saves file Interally but sad to say all of them just wont work. Also Adding android:onlick on Button Makes my App crash.

```
public void compile(View runButton) {
    String txt = editor.getText().toString();
    String fileName = "example.html";
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(fileName.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editor.setText("");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "FNF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
}
```

Comment: `Is it possible to Save a file on Internal Storage using different kinds of extensions? `. No. A file can have only one extension. Obvious i think.

Comment: Further your code looks ok. But why are you only writing the filename to that file? Why not `txt`? And why call that function 'compile'?

Comment: @greenapps thanks for reply appreciate it..so you can only Write/Save a file using .txt extension?Yeah ive search other similar threads also,but im not sure why its not working. Also when i add onclick on my button , the App Crashes when i pressed it.

Does naming my function "compile" makes things complicated? i mean does the system have a similar code for "compile"?

Comment: You can give your file any extension you want. Not only .txt. And a file can have only one extension. Why are you not posting code for onClick if you have problems there? And the logcat? The logcat tells you exactly what goes wrong. Dont name a function compile when it does not compile. You dont wanna write unreadable code do you?

Comment: Sorry about not posting the code. So if i wanna save my file with the extension .html, then it is possible?